# Fitting a distribution given the histogram using scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, probability, curve-fitting

I would like to fit a distribution using scipy (in my case, using weibull_min) to my data. Is it possible to do this given the Histogram, and not the data points? In my case, because the histogram has integer bins of size 1, I know that I can extrapolate my data in the following way:

```py
import numpy as np
orig_hist = np.array([10, 5, 3, 2, 1])

ext_data = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, [[i]*x for i, x in enumerate(orig_hist)])
```

In this case, ext_data would hold this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
```

And building the histogram using:

```
np.histogram(ext_data, bins=5)
```

would be equivalent to orig_hist

Yet, given that I already have the histogram built, I would like to avoid extrapolating the data and use orig_hist to fit the distribution, but I don't know if it is possible to use it directly in the fitting procedure. Additionally, is there a numpy function that can be used to perform something similar to the extrapolation I showed?

Comment: I added an answer based on `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`, but then I realized that you wanted to use `stats.weibull_min.fit`. If I understand correctly, you need the `ext_data` for the latter. As it happens, the histogram is enough for the former. Could my answer work for you?

Comment: I don't think so, to be honest. I followed the steps in your answer, but using my data instead, and the resulting fit was not good. There seems to be an issue with `optimize.cuver_fit`, because no matter what data I use as input, the popt value returned is `1.00000001`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding something, but I believe that fitting to the histogram is exactly what you should do: you're trying to approximate the probability density. And the histogram is as close as you can get to the underlying probability density. You just have to normalize it in order to have an integral of 1, or allow your fitted model to contain an arbitrary prefactor.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import scipy.optimize as opt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

orig_hist = np.array([10, 5, 3, 2, 1])
norm_hist = orig_hist/float(sum(orig_hist))

popt,pcov = opt.curve_fit(lambda x,c: stats.weibull_min.pdf(x,c), np.arange(len(norm_hist)),norm_hist)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(norm_hist,'o-',label='norm_hist')
plt.plot(stats.weibull_min.pdf(np.arange(len(norm_hist)),popt),'s-',label='Weibull_min fit')
plt.legend()
```

Of course for your given input the Weibull fit will be far from satisfactory:

[image: fit to data]

### Update

As I mentioned above, Weibull_min is a poor fit to your sample input. The bigger problem is that it is also a poor fit to your actual data:

```
orig_hist = np.array([ 23., 14., 13., 12., 12., 12., 11., 11., 11., 11., 10., 10., 10., 9., 9., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6.], dtype=np.float32)
```

[image: new histogram data]

There are two main problems with this histogram. The first, as I said, is that it is unlikely to correspond to a Weibull_min distribution: it is maximal near zero and has a long tail, so it needs a non-trivial combination of Weibull parameters. Furthermore, your histogram clearly only contains a part of the distribution. This implies that my normalizing suggestion above is guaranteed to fail. You can't avoid using an arbitrary scale parameter in your fit.

I manually defined a scaled Weibull fitting function [according to the formula on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution#Definition):

```
my_weibull = lambda x,l,c,A: A*float(c)/l*(x/float(l))**(c-1)*np.exp(-(x/float(l))**c)
```

In this function `x` is the independent variable, `l` is `lambda` (the scale parameter), `c` is `k` (the shape parameter) and `A` is a scaling prefactor. The faint upside of introducing `A` is that you don't have to normalize your histogram.

Now, when I dropped this function into `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`, I found what you did: it doesn't actually perform a fit, but sticks with the initial fitting parameters, whatever you set (using the `p0` parameter; the default guesses are all 1 for every parametr). *And* `curve_fit` seems to think that the fitting converged.

After more than an hour's wall-related head-banging, I realized that the problem is that the singular behaviour at `x=0` throws off the nonlinear least-squares algorithm. By excluding your *very first* data point, you get an actual fit to your data. I suspect that if we set `c=1` and don't allow that to fit, then this problem might go away, but it is probably more informative to allow that to be fitted (so I didn't check).

Here's the corresponding code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

orig_hist = np.array([ 23., 14., 13., 12., 12., 12., 11., 11., 11., 11., 10., 10., 10., 9., 9., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6.], dtype=np.float32)

my_weibull = lambda x,l,c,A: A*float(c)/l*(x/float(l))**(c-1)*np.exp(-(x/float(l))**c)

popt,pcov = opt.curve_fit(my_weibull,np.arange(len(orig_hist))[1:],orig_hist[1:]) #throw away x=0!

plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(len(orig_hist)),orig_hist,'o-',label='orig_hist')
plt.plot(np.arange(len(orig_hist)),my_weibull(np.arange(len(orig_hist)),*popt),'s-',label='Scaled Weibull fit')
plt.legend()
```

Result:

[image: new fit]

```
In [631]: popt
Out[631]: array([  1.10511850e+02,   8.82327822e-01,   1.05206207e+03])
```

the final fitted parameters are in the order `(l,c,A)`, with the shape parameter of around `0.88`. This corresponds to a diverging probability density, which explains why a few errors pop up saying

> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power

and why there isn't a data point from the fitting for `x=0`. But judging from the visual agreement between data and fit, you can assess whether the result is acceptable or not.

If you want to overdo it, you can probably try generating points using `np.random.weibull` with these parameters, then comparing the resulting histograms with your own.

Comment: Thanks, this seems close to what I'm trying to do. My issue was that I was trying to fit using stats.weibull_min.fit. But that particular method takes as input the data to be fitted. If I understood it correctly, in your case, you used the optimize.curve_fit function to fit the data, passing to it the function you want to fit (weibull_min.pdf), and the X and Y values.

Comment: @AlbertoA I used `curve_fit` to fit the probability density *to the histogram*, which is the approximation of the probability density based on your raw data. Have you tried using `curve_fit` on the actual histogram? Did that also return `popt=1.0001`?

Comment: Yeah, it did return the same value. I normalized the histogram, dividing it by its sum, then tried `curve_fit`, and the result was the same `1.00000001` I got when using the dummy histogram of the example in my question.

Comment: Do you have an idea of what `c` should be in the fit? At least a ballpark figure? You can set that as a starting point for `curve_fit`, which should probably help. Are your actual data more distributed according to Weibull (i.e. does your histogram tend to 0 as x->0, at least if that is how weibull_min looks like)?

Comment: Looking at some Weibull plots, I would say that the shape parameter `c` would be either < 1 or equal to 1. The following array is an example of my data (histogram): `array([ 23.,  14.,  13.,  12.,  12.,  12.,  11.,  11.,  11.,  11.,  10., 10.,  10.,   9.,   9.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   8., 8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   7.,   7.,   7.,   7.,   7.,   7.,   7., 7.,   7.,   7.,   7.,   7.,   7.,   6.,   6.,   6.,   6.,   6., 6.,   6.,   6.,   6.,   6.,   6.], dtype=float32)`
Now that you said, I'm also not sure weibull_min is the best fit for my data (It has to be some weibull, though).

Comment: @AlbertoA I believe I solved the issue, the main problem was that `x=0` broke the fitting algorithm. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Andras, thank you for the very complete answer. Its interesting, because I've been playing with Matlab's Weibull fit (which can work by passing the X values and their frequencies, as I wanted), and the function complained when tried to use a value of x=0, but I don't know if it is related to the `curve_fit`issue as well. Also, as you suspected, the histogram is only a part my distribution. I still need to experiment a bit more on how to work with my data so I can fit a Weibull distribution to it. My examples with Matlab seem good so far, but I hope to reproduce them in python!

Comment: @AlbertoA unfortunately, from what I've seen while I was working on this problem, matlab's Curve Fitting Toolbox is much more flexible and smart than `scipy.optimize`. For instance, I routinely use lower and upper bounds for the parameters when fitting in matlab, but I don't see how that could be done in python (even after looking at `scipy.optimize.leastsq`, which `curve_fit` uses under the hood.