# Histogram fitting with python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scipy, data-analysis

I've been surfing but haven't found the correct method to do the following.

I have a histogram done with matplotlib:

```
hist, bins, patches = plt.hist(distance, bins=100, normed='True')
```

From the plot, I can see that the distribution is more or less an exponential (Poisson distribution). How can I do the *best fitting*, taking into account my hist and bins arrays?

**UPDATE**

I am using the following approach:

```
x = np.float64(bins) # Had some troubles with data types float128 and float64
hist = np.float64(hist)
myexp=lambda x,l,A:A*np.exp(-l*x)
popt,pcov=opt.curve_fit(myexp,(x[1:]+x[:-1])/2,hist)
```

But I get

```
---> 41 plt.plot(stats.expon.pdf(np.arange(len(hist)),popt),'-')

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,) (2,)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828184/fitting-to-poisson-histogram or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620471/fitting-empirical-distribution-to-theoretical-ones-with-scipy-python ?

Comment: I am not sure why you would want to use the histogram for that. All common distributions can be fixed by a couple of shape/location parameters. These can usually be estimated very efficiently from the data itself.

Comment: I answered a similar question [yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767491/fitting-a-distribution-given-the-histogram-using-scipy/33768053#33768053), you can even find there how to use a fitting model of your own. You should take as input `x=(bins[1:]+bins[:-1])/2; y=hist` for the fitting procedure. @cel: for noisy data, a least-squares fit can be much more reliable than the raw estimate of the moments of the distribution.([citation needed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citation_needed))

Comment: I don't understand too much what you give there. I am trying to use `param=spy.expon.fit(distance); a = np.linspace(0,bins[-1],1000, dtype='f'); pdf_fitted=spy.expon.pdf(a,loc=param[0],scale=param[1]);plt.plot(a,pdf_fitted,'r-')`

Comment: That might work, but that's another approach. My linked answer is based on `spy.optimize.curve_fit`, and works with the histogram rather than the raw data (as per your question). For this you'd first define a fitting model `myexp=lambda x,l,A:A*np.exp(-l*x)`, then use it as `popt,pcov=spy.optimize.curve_fit(myexp,bins[1:]+bins[:-1])/2,hist)`. Then `popt` contains `(l,A)`, i.e. the parameter of the exponential distribution and the prefactor for fitting. Does this make more sense?

Comment: Yes, that is true about the approach I give before.  This is so far I can get (updating the question).

Comment: Don't `plt.plot(stats.expon.pdf(np.arange(len(hist)),popt),'-')`, rather `plt.plot((x[1:]+x[:-1])/2,myexp((x[1:]+x[:-1])/2,*popt),'-')` (or with any `x` array you prefer).

Comment: Okey, thank you so much.

Comment: [Here are all the `scipy.stats` distributions PDFs with example code.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37559471/2087463)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you described is a form of [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution), and you want to estimate the parameters of the exponential distribution, given the probability density observed in your data.  Instead of using non-linear regression method (which assumes the residue errors are Gaussian distributed), one correct way is arguably a MLE (maximum likelihood estimation).

`scipy` provides a large number of continuous distributions in its `stats` library, and the MLE is implemented with the `.fit()` method. Of course, exponential distribution is [there](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.expon.html):

```
In [1]:

import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as ss
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
In [2]:
#generate data 
X = ss.expon.rvs(loc=0.5, scale=1.2, size=1000)

#MLE
P = ss.expon.fit(X)
print P
(0.50046056920696858, 1.1442947648425439)
#not exactly 0.5 and 1.2, due to being a finite sample

In [3]:
#plotting
rX = np.linspace(0,10, 100)
rP = ss.expon.pdf(rX, *P)
#Yup, just unpack P with *P, instead of scale=XX and shape=XX, etc.
In [4]:

#need to plot the normalized histogram with `normed=True`
plt.hist(X, normed=True)
plt.plot(rX, rP)
Out[4]:
```

[image]

Your `distance` will replace `X` here.

Comment: [Here are all the `scipy.stats` distributions PDFs with example code.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37559471/2087463)

Comment: `normed` is deprecated it is now called `density`